# Meaning and usage of the swear word pronounced /ˈkʰʌnt/?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

I’ve been hearing the word *cunt* used several times now. What kind of situations do you usually use this word, and what sort of person does this swear word usually describe?

Comment: Already discussed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7059/why-is-cnt-so-much-more-derogatory-in-the-us-than-the-uk/17977#17977) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11981/what-is-currently-the-most-obscene-word-in-british-english/12037#12037)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word has at least three definitions:

> 1. [British English slang](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cunt?q=cunt): "an offensive word for a very unpleasant or stupid person"
> 2. "offensive for the vagina"
> 3. [American English slang](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cunt): "usually disparaging & obscene : woman"

Polite people usually don't use this word. It's always considered vulgar and offensive, and it's certainly considered politically incorrect. Besides, it's not nice to use disparaging epithets to describe anyone. Passive knowledge of this kind of language is always useful, but try to keep it out of your active vocabulary.

There are always exceptions to every rule, of course. D. H. Lawrence used the word to great effect in *[Lady Chatterly's Lover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Chatterley%27s_Lover)*. Shakespeare used the euphemism "country matters" in *[Hamlet](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/hamlet/full.html)* (Act III, Scene 2):

> HAMLET: Lady, shall I lie in your lap?
> (Lying down at OPHELIA's feet)
> OPHELIA: No, my lord.
> HAMLET: I mean, my head upon your lap?
> OPHELIA: Ay, my lord.
> HAMLET: Do you think I meant country matters?
> OPHELIA: I think nothing, my lord.
> HAMLET: That's a fair thought to lie between maids' legs.
> OPHELIA: What is, my lord?
> HAMLET: Nothing.

Answer (score -3):

It could refer to someone you view as unpleasant or stupid.
It's used similarly to *fag*, *faggot* and *douchebag*.